# Seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined in console"

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

In a process of hiding piece of content for people who didn't like our page yet. Using Facebook SDK for the first time. The idea is to have a call to action text and button. Once button is clicked, if user already likes our page- it shows a piece of content. If not- shows a like button and shows piece of content after it's clicked.

Here is connecting SDK

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : '348511868693215',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

   (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And here is actual code for checking

```
   FB.api({
    method:     "pages.isFan",
    page_id:        page_id,
    },  function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response){
            //if liked
        $(".show-poll").click(function(){
        $(".actualpoll").show();
        });
        } else {
            $(".show-poll").click(function(){
        $(".likepage").show();
        });
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: On what line of code do you write `var FB`? What do you think it the variable *should* evaluate to?

Comment: *"And here is actual code for checking"* Where is that code in relation to the other? It probably runs before the SDK was included. There is reason why you created the `window.fbAsyncInit` function: It is called when the SDK is available. Hence your other code must be inside or called from that function.

Comment: "checking code" is right after sdk connecting code

Comment: _“In a process of hiding piece of content for people who didn't like our page yet”_ – Like Gating is not allowed any more by Facebook; you need to show the same content to people whether they have liked your page or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code "for checking" is executed before the SDK is loaded, i.e. before `FB` is available. Move the code inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` function. That function is called once the SDK is available.

Comment: So, I wrapped the "checking code" in *window.fbAsyncInit = function() {* and *};*  Now I get  sdk.js:90 Uncaught ReferenceError: page_id is not defined
    at window.fbAsyncInit ((index):310)
    at v.__wrapper (sdk.js:90)
    at sdk.js:133

Comment: Well, you haven't declared `page_id` anywhere, so that error is expected. I assumed it would be defined somewhere, otherwise why would you have it in your code in the first place?

Comment: What an epic fail... Added page id, but still get the same errors

Comment: Since only you have access to your full code and can debug it properly, you need to figure this out on your own. It's a separate issue anyway.